# Using Hibernate 5.0.7 with JPA 2.1 on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I am learning `JPA 2.1` and `JAX-RS` on `Tomcat 8.5`. I created a Java project for `JPA 2.1` with `Hibernate` to talk to `MySQL 5.7` in `Eclipse Oxygen`. It worked fine.

Then I created a web project with `Jersey` and `Jackson 2.24.1`. It works well as `RSETful web service` on `Tomcat 8.5`.

But after I tried to set the first project (JPA one) as a dependency of the second project(web service one) and call the following code on the Tomcat:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = 
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DataDefinition-Core-Type");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

### I got the following message errors. Any suggestions?

```
22:57:37,956  INFO QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
22:57:38,193 ERROR ErrorCounter:60 - <AST>:1:76: unexpected AST node: null
22:57:38,195 ERROR ErrorCounter:55 - <AST>:1:76: unexpected AST node: null
<AST>:1:76: unexpected AST node: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2455)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.aliasedSelectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2490)
    at ...

org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Dec 14, 2016 10:57:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.combivice.datadefinition.ws.MainApplication] in context with path [/DataDefinition-WebService] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.setAlias(HqlSqlWalker.java:1097)

...
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
    at com.combivice.datadefinition.query.ObjectTypeQuery.matchTypeNameOrAlias(ObjectTypeQuery.java:59)
    at com.combivice.datadefinition.ws.QueryTypeAndAttributeService.findTypeWithNameAndAttrbutes(QueryTypeAndAttributeService.java:153)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at 

 ...
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error seems to happen in QueryTypeAndAttributeService.java, line 153, calling ObjectTypeQuery.matchTypeNameOrAlias, in ObjectTypeQuery.java, at line 59. And it looks like that code tries creating an invalid query.

Comment: Thanks, JB. The puzzling part is that I still got the same error even I commented the query and only left the two JPA statements I mentioned in the code:

Comment: creating an EntityManagerFactory and an EntityManager.

Comment: I use Maven to manage JPA, JAX-WS and other third party libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I created a new web application, added the dependent JPA project and tested it out. The code worked. I looked into the MAVEN dependencies I put into this new web application. The only difference between the MAVEN dependencies in this new web application and in the original JAX-RS application is that it does not contain the following Maven dependency:
    
        org.slf4j
        slf4j-log4j12
        1.6.1
    
After I commented out the above dependency in the original JAX-WS application. the problem is gone. Don't see the reported error messages any more.

Some additional background information:
The above Maven dependency is included in the original JPA project, which was developed in Eclipse Mars and imported to Eclipse Oxygen.